# Contextual treatment of cell references by Excel formula

Tags: excel-formula

could someone explain to me why this formula works:

```
={SUMPRODUCT((INDIRECT("TabName!"&A1&":a16"))*1)}
```

Where:

```
A1 = ADDRESS(8,COLUMN(),1,1) = $A$8
```

yet this does not:

```
={SUMPRODUCT((INDIRECT("TabName!"&ADDRESS(8,COLUMN(),1,1)&":a16"))*1)} 

= #Value!
```

The formula is in column A, so resolves the same as A1.

Excel is clearly treating the results of the same formula differently depending on the context - either referring to the result in another cell (A1), or if incorporated into the formula itself.

I wouldn't even know what to start looking for in terms of researching the phenomenon, so please forgive me if it's been explained many times before.

Is there a solution? I don't really want to use cells to calculate cell references only to be used by other formula.

Also, the above is an extract of a larger forumula, so I appreciate the logic of it doesn't make sense in isolation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `SUMPRODUCT` is a special case of an array formula `SUM`. So when you write

`=SUMPRODUCT((INDIRECT("Sheet8!"&ADDRESS(8,COLUMN(),1,1)&":a16"))*1)` it treats `Column()` as array and instead of giving you `1` it gives `{1}` which results in evaluation as follows:

> `=SUMPRODUCT((INDIRECT("Sheet8!"&ADDRESS(8,COLUMN(),1,1)&":a16"))*1)`
>   `=SUMPRODUCT((INDIRECT("Sheet8!"&ADDRESS(8,{1},1,1)&":a16"))*1)`
>   `=SUMPRODUCT((INDIRECT("Sheet8!"& {"$A$8"} &":a16"))*1)`
>   `=SUMPRODUCT((INDIRECT({"Sheet8!$A$8:a16"}))*1)`
>   `=SUMPRODUCT((INDIRECT({*#VALUE!*"}))*1)`

Thus, `INDIRECT({"Sheet8!$A$8:a16"})` gives you ***`#VALUE`*** error.

Secondly, if you'll evaluate same formula using sum as

`=SUM((INDIRECT("Sheet8!"&ADDRESS(8,COLUMN(),1,1)&":a16")))`

`Column()` will give you `1` and not `{1}` as in the case of *SUMPRODUCT* and you'll get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, I need to either use the column() as part of the dynamic range in the array or Sumproduct... Is that possible?

Comment: @Chum3 - You can use column() using the second formula in my answer i.e.`=SUM((INDIRECT("Sheet8!"&ADDRESS(8,COLUMN(),1,1)&":a16")))`

Comment: Hmm. Can't get that to work. 
The formula I'm trying to resolve is this 
={SUM(INDIRECT("Tabname"&"!$A$8:$A$16")=$A8)*(INDIRECT("tabname!"&ADDRESS(8,COLUMN(),1,1)&":B16")))}, 
and stepping through the evaluation gets to here:
=SUM({1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0}*(Indirect({"tabname!$B$8:B16"})) 
where it falls over to #Value!

Comment: @Chum3 - Try this formula: `=SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Tabname!"&ADDRESS(8,COLUMN(),1,1)&":B16"),INDIRECT("Tabname"&"!$A$8:$A$16"),"="&$A8)`

Comment: @Chum3 - This is a normal formula so just press `Enter` and not `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`

Comment: BOOM! Yup, that's got it. I tend to default to Sumproduct / arrays out of habit. Had forgotten about Sumifs... Thank you!